# Java D20 dice roller

Tags: java, random, dice

I'm trying to create a dice rolling class for a text-based RPG in java. I'm super new to programming and looking for some help. Thanks in advance!!

```
    import java.util.Random;

    public class Dice {
        public Random random;

        public Dice() {
            this.random = new Random();
        }

        public int roll() {
            int rand = random.nextInt(20);
        }

        System.out.println("\nThe dice rolled a " + rand + ".");
    }
```

Comment: Presumably your roll() method is supposed to `return` the number you generated. Then you just need to call it.

Comment: Also, the code to print the result is outside of a method.  You will want to look up writing main methods in java (see, for example, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html).

Comment: also, your System.out.println call is "hanging". you cannot write commands like that into a class body. For a program, you need a main method, there you can create a new Dice, call the roll method, and print the result

Comment: And most importantly, you forgot to ask a question!

Comment: This is probably the least of your problems but `nextInt(20)` returns a number from 0 to 19. Since you want to simulate a d20 you need to add one. like `int rand = random.nextInt(20) + 1;`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond! :) Everyone's comment has helped me in a big way

Comment: Would you mind accepting an answer or comment to ask for more ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your statement `println` is outside a method
2. You use `rand` which is only a variable inside the `roll()` method
3. you don't return the value in `roll()` method

You need something like

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    Dice d = new Dice();
    System.out.println("The dice rolled a " + d.roll() + ".");
}

public int roll () {
    return random.nextInt(20); // value in [0;20[, so [0;19]
}
```

Comment: and as mentioned above, don't forget the `return rand;` as last statement in your roll() implementation.

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you!

Comment: @CameronJones don't hesitate to accept the answer so  ;)